# spark core wifi credentials change

Tags: c, string, serial-port, wifi, sparkcore

I'm working on a small product idea with my spark core, and setting up a serial interface for the customer to set up their product onto their wifi:

```
String newssid = wifissid(3);
String newpw = wifipw(3);
WiFi.setCredentials(newssid, newpw);
```

As you can see, I created 2 functions that over a serial connection to a pc returns the ssid and the password. I have already managed to get the setCredentials to work when I set the credentials in  the code:

```
WiFi.setCredentials("D-link7853", "thisismypassword");
```

but when I run it with the strings, as above, it doesn't want to compile. the error given is:

> serial_wifi_cred_change_3.cpp:49:39: error: no matching function for
>   call to 'WiFiClass::setCredentials(String&, String&)' }
>   serial_wifi_cred_change_3.cpp:49:39: note: candidates are: In file
>   included from ../inc/spark_wiring.h:37:0, from
>   ../inc/application.h:29, from serial_wifi_cred_change_3.cpp:2:
>   ../inc/spark_wiring_wifi.h:61:21: note: static void
>   WiFiClass::setCredentials(const char*) static void
>   setCredentials(const char *ssid); ^ ../inc/spark_wiring_wifi.h:61:21:
>   note: candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
>   ../inc/spark_wiring_wifi.h:62:21: note: static void
>   WiFiClass::setCredentials(const char*, const char*) static void
>   setCredentials(const char *ssid, const char *password); ^
>   ../inc/spark_wiring_wifi.h:62:21: note: no known conversion for
>   argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'
>   ../inc/spark_wiring_wifi.h:63:21: note: static void
>   WiFiClass::setCredentials(const char*, const char*, long unsigned int)
>   static void setCredentials(const char *ssid, const char *password,
>   unsigned long security); ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Christian Loris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28423272/83055) is right.

`setCredentials` expects SSID and password to be `char *` type. Your code should look like this:

```
String newssid = "foo";
String newpw = "bar";

char newssidBuf[newssid.length()];
char newpwBuf[newpw.length()];
newssid.toCharArray(newssidBuf, newssid.length());
newpw.toCharArray(newpwBuf, newpw.length());

WiFi.setCredentials(newssidBuf, newpwBuf);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error states it doesn't want a string but rather a pointer to const char array.  It looks like the documentation on the site is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer.. but I am solving a similar problem to you using a smartconfig system from texas instruments? Smartconfig is used to pass wifi details to the core in the spark app, and TexasInstruments provide a sample app that you can modify.

Good luck

Comment: It doesn't provide an answer, but it is the only help that the user has received in a month. I cannot comment on Mr_James's question because I do not have the reputation. What are you actually suggesting that we do to help the op?